# How to add chapter and page number in LATEX?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

[image]

How can i solve this? Can anyone help me out!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please have a look on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and provide us a MWE.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-pagebychap.html